# Is there an way of implementing an minimum deceleration speed in an UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiscrollview

I have an UIScrollView that contains some UIImageViews which are animated. It really only looks cool if there's a minimum scrolling speed happening. But when the user slowly scrolls and lifts the finger, the UIScrollView decelerates very slowly.

The problem is, that the scrollViewDidScroll method doesn't get called upon every offset change. It get's called by a kind of time interval as long as the offset is changing. The interval is always the same, regardless of how fast the user scrolls.

Answer (score 1):

If we were allowed to talk about iPhone OS 3.0, somebody might be able to tell you that UIScrollView might have a new property called decelerationRate. But unfortunately we are not allowed to talk about iPhone OS 3.0 :(